# call javascript function invoked in created element in another function

Tags: javascript

I have 2 functions additem and removeitem , I wantehen I click remove button the whole line created in additem removed ( note : the function additem works fine but remove item does nothing so I believe the problem is just in my javascript code )

```
var sum =0 ;
var total=0 ;
var i = 1 ;

function additem ( name , price ) {
    document.getElementById("selecteditems").innerHTML += "<p class='selected"+i+"'  >"  +  name  +  " :   " + price + " L.E" ;
    document.getElementById("removebtn").innerHTML += "<p class='selected"+i+"'>" + "<button id='selected"+i+"' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='removeitem("+i+" , "+price+" ) ' style='font-size: 15px; height: 20px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;' >Remove</button> " ;
    i++ ;
    sum += price ;
    }

function removeitem ( i , price ) {

    document.getElementsByClassName("selected"+i ).innerHTML="" ;
    sum -= price ;
    }
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a nodelist, not a single node, and therefore you can't set `innerHTML` on it. You probably want `getElementsByClassName("selected"+i )[0].innerHTML` instead.

Comment: I tried replace class by id and used getelementbyid, this removed the item and price but not the button . I asked and knew that getElementById  find only the first element . so could you suggest a way that I can remove the whole created line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this solution and it worked . so instead of using one id for multiple elements. use different id for each element and in the removitem function I used 2 document.getElementById for each element . here is the solution according to my code

```
var sum =0 ;
var total=0 ;
var i = 1 ;

function additem ( name , price ) {
    document.getElementById("selecteditems").innerHTML += "<p id='selected"+i+"'  >"  +  name  +  " :   " + price + " L.E" ;
    document.getElementById("removebtn").innerHTML += "<p id='B"+i+"'>" + "<button id='selected"+i+"' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='removeitem("+i+" , "+price+" ) ' style='font-size: 15px; height: 20px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;' >Remove</button> " ;
    i++ ;
    sum += price ;
    }

function removeitem ( i , price ) {

    document.getElementById("selected"+i ).innerHTML="" ;
    document.getElementById("B"+i ).innerHTML="" ;
    sum -= price ;
    }
```